# "Error: No provider for Sugerir!" in ionic 3 typescript/angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm with a problem in one of my pages. When i click to open, the error

> > "No provider for Sugerir" is shown in the page is "novolocal.ts". All the app is openning and working fine, including "Sugerir.ts".

**My novolocal.ts**

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component, NgZone, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { MapProxPage } from '../Map-prox/Map-prox';
import { ProjetoTCCBrendaPage } from '../projeto-tccbrenda/projeto-tccbrenda';
import { listaProxPage } from '../lista-prox/lista-prox';
import { CadastroPage } from '../cadastro/cadastro';
import { myService } from '../services/data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-novolocal',
  templateUrl: 'novolocal.html'
})

export class NovolocalPage {

  public event = {
    month: '10-05-2018',
    timeStarts: '09:00',
    timeEnds: '10-05-2018'
  }
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private _myService: myService) {    
    console.log(this._myService.getData());

  }



  goToMapProxPage(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
this.navCtrl.push(MapProxPage);
  }goToProjetoTCCBrenda(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(ProjetoTCCBrendaPage);
  }goTolistaProx(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(listaProxPage);
  }goToCadastro(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(CadastroPage);
  }goToNovolocal(params){
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(NovolocalPage);
  }
}
```

**My app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { ProjetoTCCBrendaPage } from '../pages/projeto-tccbrenda/projeto-tccbrenda';
import { listaProxPage } from '../pages/lista-prox/lista-prox';
import { CadastroPage } from '../pages/cadastro/cadastro';
import { NovolocalPage } from '../pages/novolocal/novolocal';
import { MapProxPage } from '../pages/Map-prox/Map-prox';
import { SugerirPage } from '../pages/sugerir/sugerir';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation'; 
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { myService } from '../pages/services/data.service';


import {
  AngularFireDatabaseModule,
} from "angularfire2/database";
import {
  AngularFireDatabase,
  FirebaseObjectObservable,
  FirebaseListObservable
} from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import { AngularFireAuthModule, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { SugestoesPage } from '../pages/sugestoes/sugestoes';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';
import { GoogleMaps } from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';



var config = {
  apiKey: "hereismyapikey",
  authDomain: "geoloc-121315.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://geoloc-121315.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "geoloc-121315",
  storageBucket: "geoloc-179420.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "mymsgid"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ProjetoTCCBrendaPage,
    listaProxPage,
    MapProxPage,
    CadastroPage,
    NovolocalPage,
    SugestoesPage,
    HomePage,
    SugerirPage

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDvXaxJqvlH_84DrxytYNF341Ax67H1OU8",
      libraries: ["places"]
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    ProjetoTCCBrendaPage,
    listaProxPage,
    CadastroPage,
    NovolocalPage,
    MapProxPage,
    SugerirPage,
    SugestoesPage,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    GoogleMaps,
    AngularFireDatabase,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    Geolocation, //provider p geoloc nativo
    myService,
    Device
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
```

}

**My Sugerir.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MapProxPage } from '../Map-prox/Map-prox';
import { ProjetoTCCBrendaPage } from '../projeto-tccbrenda/projeto-tccbrenda';
import { listaProxPage } from '../lista-prox/lista-prox';
import { CadastroPage } from '../cadastro/cadastro';
import { NovolocalPage } from '../novolocal/novolocal';
import { SugestoesPage } from '../sugestoes/sugestoes';
import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import {
  AngularFireDatabase,
  FirebaseObjectObservable,
  FirebaseListObservable
} from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';


export class Sugerir {//para cadastrar
  id: string;
  cidade: string;
  melhordia: string;
  melhorhora: string;
  pub: string;
  tipo: string;
  uf: string;
  valor: string;

}

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-sugerir',
  templateUrl: 'sugerir.html',
})
export class SugerirPage {
  sugerir: Sugerir; //para cadastrar
  sugestoes: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;//para exibir e cadastrar


  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.sugestoes = this.db.list('/sugestoes');//para exibir e cadastrar

    this.sugerir = new Sugerir();//para cadastrar

  }



  cadastrar() {//para cadastrar
    this.sugestoes.push(this.sugerir).then(() => {
      this.sugerir = new Sugerir();
    });
    alert("Salvo!");
  }

  goToMapProxPage(params) {
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(MapProxPage);
  } goToProjetoTCCBrenda(params) {
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(ProjetoTCCBrendaPage);
  } goTolistaProx(params) {
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(listaProxPage);
  } goToCadastro(params) {
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(CadastroPage);
  } goToSugerir(params) {
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(SugerirPage);
  } goToSugestoes(params) {
    if (!params) params = {};
    this.navCtrl.push(SugestoesPage);
  }
}
```

I really don't understand the relation between "novolocal.ts" and "sugerir.ts" what can cause this error.

Comment: once comment out constructor in your `novolocal.ts` and try it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's working now. Thanks for the help :)

Look like caused by the duplicate classes with the same name, so i only changed the name.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `export class Sugerir` to `export interface Sugerir`

Comment: Thank you, this help me in some way.
But now the app is with other error: "Can't resolve all parameters for HomePage"... oh god, i'm new in this and have many errors...